# iMessage displaying conversation threads out of order on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I've been having some big issues with my iPhone lately, but the most infuriating one by far is that my messages are not displayed in chronological order. The usual way is that a new message from a contact brings that thread to the top of the list, but about two weeks ago, my threads got sorted into a completely random order and, worse, when I get a new message, that thread isn't bumped to the top anymore.

So, when I get a new message, I have to scroll quite a ways to even find it. I've tried updating iOS on my phone. I've restarted my phone, turned off iMessage then back on, deactivated iMessage on my Macbook and reactivated just to see, and nothing's worked. Anyone have any ideas what the heck is going on here? This is on an iPhone 6 with iOS 10.3.2.

[image]

Comment: What's the time and date on your iPhone?

Comment: @JashJacob The time and date are correct, and in the date & time settings, I have it set to "set automatically"

Comment: Intresting. I've noticed such a mismatch happening when the date and time settings have gone wonky. Could you attach a screenshot with the timestamps showing in the message list view?

Comment: My daughter is having a similar problem but her phone is not an iPhone.  If I send her a message from my iMac she receives them but not in chronological order. If I send them from my iPhone she receives them fine.

Comment: @JashJacob I edited my original post with a screenshot

Comment: My daughter is having same problem when I send messages from iMac.  They are ok if sent from my iphone.  She doesn't have iPhone.

Comment: I'm having this same issue! Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/212519)

Answer (score 1):

My children sometimes change the date / time on my phone so that they can trick certain games that they play on it.  Then, my messages no longer sort correctly.  I just fixed my phone by setting the date and time to update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off the Set Automatically option in the time settings and rebooted the phone.  It fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you explain why that might help?